# How timing function execution works in go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to time the execution of a function but it always returns `0ns`, which is hard to believe. Added a 1ns sleep in between but it does strange things (when uncommented). Here is the code:

```golang
func pow2(base, exponent int64) int64 {
    var result int64 = 1
    for ; exponent > 0; exponent >>= 1 {
        result *= base
    }
    return result
}
```

```golang
func Test_pow2(*testing.T) {
    var base, exponent, n, expected int64 = 2, 256, 0, 0
    var start time.Time
    var duration time.Duration

    start = time.Now()
    n = fastExponentiationAlgorithm(base, exponent)
    //time.Sleep(1 * time.Nanosecond)
    duration = time.Since(start)
    expected = math.Pow(base, exponent)
    if n != expected {
        fmt.Errorf("expected %+v but got %+v", expected, n)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("pow2(%+v, %+v) executed in %dns\n", base, exponent, duration / time.Nanosecond)
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can point out my mistake,
regards.

---

Edit: A benchmark was generated, as suggested by [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7426/adrian) and [hymns for disco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11424673/hymns-for-disco), which resulted as the following:

```golang
func Benchmark_pow2(b *testing.B) {
    var base, exponent, n, expected int64 = 2, 10, 0, 0

    expected = math.Pow(base, exponent)

    b.ResetTimer()
    n = pow2(base, exponent)
    b.StopTimer()

    if n != expected {
        b.Errorf("expected %d but got %d", expected, n)
    }
}
```

After executing it, this output is generated:

```
Benchmark_pow2
    test1_test.go:44: expected 20 but got 16
--- FAIL: Benchmark_pow2
```

`What is happening in here? why is it failing in this way?`

Comment: 1) for readability, don't put unrelated calls on the same line; 2) for benchmarking, use [benchmarks](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks), not tests; 3) your test may take less time than the granularity of your system clock.

Comment: 1) I will fix that now and 2) `why is benchmarking better than actually using the time package?`

Comment: Read the docs and it should be pretty clear - benchmarks will run the code multiple times in order to get an accurate read on execution time.

Comment: Check the benchmark examples carefully. You need to implement the for loop correctly or else the testing system won't work correctly.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I reckon the `pow2` function might be wrong but it surprises me that even the standard `math.Pow` is also failing... also I don't see anything strange in the for loop but I have little experience with Go so idk

Comment: I meant in your `Benchmark_pow2`. The benchmark should have a `for i := 0; i <b.N; i++` just like the benchmark examples. Also, you should keep your benchmarking and testing separate. Make a testing function to verify correctness, and a benchmark function only for measurement. If you put testing code in your benchmark, it will affect your measurements.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco but the benchmark is independent from the function... I don't understand why do you say so. Also, I created a separate test function and `math.pow(2,10)` still computes as 16...

Comment: @HymnsForDisco nevermind, I just discovered that integer variables (at least) are passed by reference in Go

Comment: I wasn't commenting about the correctness of the function yet since there was still a problem with the benchmark implementation you showed. About the incorrect test results, this is a new question and should be asked on a new post. You will need to try to isolate and reproduce the problem, because the numbers you're showing now are not really coherent.

Comment: Please post a new question about this (if you wish to explore it further). Integer values are not passed by reference, so I think there is some other misunderstanding you have about your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effective precision of the time package is not that great. Even though the value goes to "nanosecond precision", that doesn't mean the time actually updates every nanosecond. From my own testing, the resolution of the current time is effectively 100 nanoseconds and only updates about every 0.5 milliseconds. This will most likely vary depending on your OS, hardware, and other factors.

If you want to time things the right way, read about [benchmarks](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) in the testing package. Benchmarks offer better precision because they run your code multiple times in a loop, to get the *average* execution time. This allows you to measure times which would be too small when not aggregated (like in your case).

Comment: The precision of the time package is fine, it's whatever resolution your system clock returns, though there's obviously problems trying to measure intervals in the same order of magnitude as the time it takes to call the time functions themselves.

Comment: @JimB I've edited the phrasing slightly now, but edits are welcome if you think there's a problem with the answer.

Comment: Thank you, benchmarking is  a very nice feature. Is it possible to create multiple timers inside a single benchmark?

Comment: @loko: as soon as you introduce multiple timers, you have confounding variables. Making benchmarks that measure features in isolation will give you more reliable data to work with.

Comment: "The effective precision of the time package is not that great" - the precision of `time` is 1ns, it's limited by the precision of the system clock, not the `time` package code.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I updated the code with your suggestion but it's failing in a surprising way... do you know what is happening inside the benchmark?

Comment: @Adrian I understand,  my answer is meant to address the practical side of things. Perhaps my words choice isn't the best, but again edits are welcome. Again think of it in practical terms. If there was a product sold to you on the promise of "nanosecond precision", and then these were the results you saw after handing over your money, you would probably not endorse this claim to other consumers for anything other than pedantry

Comment: True, but if you buy a smartwatch and it gets the time wrong, and you declared the watch to be inaccurate when it's actually just reporting inaccurate time it gets from your phone, that would be a highly misleading claim and entirely misattribute the cause of the problem, unfairly maligning the watch for something it has nothing to do with. The problem isn't the `time` package, it's the system clock.